# Velostrata Migration from On-premises to GCP. Error log: echo boot failed and waiting for disks online

Tags: google-cloud-platform, migration, vmware, google-migrate-for-compute-engine

I am seeing the errors in the log: echo boot failed and waiting for disks online in the console log of Velostrata Manager while I am doing the migration of a windows 2016 VM (No Symantec End Point Protection) from on-premises vcenter to Google Cloud Platform. Below is the error log for a quick reference. Answers are welcome and much appreciated. I am trying for the resolution from one day, but no luck. Thank you.

```
2019-11-27 07:28:51.623 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} 2019/11/27 07:24:36.874Z Waiting for disks to be available...
2019-11-27 07:28:51.623 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} 2019/11/27 07:24:38.937Z Waiting for disks to be available...
2019-11-27 07:28:51.623 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} 2019/11/27 07:24:40.968Z Waiting for disks to be available...
2019-11-27 07:28:51.623 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} 2019/11/27 07:24:43.015Z Waiting for disks to be available...
2019-11-27 07:28:51.623 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} 2019/11/27 07:24:45.062Z Waiting for disks to be available...
2019-11-27 07:28:51.623 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} 2019/11/27 07:24:47.093Z Waiting for disks to be available...
2019-11-27 07:28:51.623 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} 2019/11/27 07:24:49.140Z Waiting for disks to be available...
2019-11-27 07:28:51.623 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} 2019/11/27 07:24:51.187Z Waiting for disks to be available...
2019-11-27 07:28:51.623 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} 2019/11/27 07:24:53.218Z Waiting for disks to be available...
2019-11-27 07:28:51.623 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} 2019/11/27 07:24:55.265Z Waiting for disks to be available...
2019-11-27 07:28:51.623 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} 2019/11/27 07:24:57.312Z Waiting for disks to be available...
2019-11-27 07:28:51.623 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} 2019/11/27 07:24:59.343Z Waiting for disks to be available...
2019-11-27 07:28:51.623 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} 2019/11/27 07:25:01.390Z Waiting for disks to be available...
2019-11-27 07:28:51.623 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} 2019/11/27 07:25:03.437Z Waiting for disks to be available...
2019-11-27 07:28:51.623 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} ============================ port: 2 ============================
2019-11-27 07:28:51.623 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} ============================ port: 3 ============================
2019-11-27 07:28:51.623 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} ============================ port: 4 ============================
2019-11-27 07:28:52.405 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} #!ipxe
2019-11-27 07:28:52.405 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} # iqn:iqn.2014-05.com.velostrata.iscsi.base:vlst-6
2019-11-27 07:28:52.405 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} # ip1:10.120.22.11
2019-11-27 07:28:52.405 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} # ip2:10.120.22.12
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} # token:haeth2vp
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} # mode:normal
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} # boot:bios
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} :setenv
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} set syslog 10.120.22.11
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} route
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} set net0/hostname vlsboot
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} set initiator-iqn iqn.2014-05.com.velostrata.int.haeth2vp:vlst-6
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} set tgt1 iscsi:10.120.22.11
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} set tgt2 iscsi:10.120.22.12
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} set iqn iqn.2014-05.com.velostrata.iscsi.base:vlst-6
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} echo Initiator IQN ${initiator-iqn}
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} echo Target root path ${tgt1}::::${iqn}
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} echo Target replica path ${tgt2}::::${iqn}
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} :hookretry
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} inc hook-attempt
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} echo Hook attempt ${hook-attempt} at ${unixtimestr}
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} clear hook-error
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} isset ${drive1} || sanhook --drive 0x81 --no-describe ${tgt1}:::1:${iqn} ${tgt2}:::1:${iqn} && inc drive1 || inc hook-error
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} isset ${hook-error} || goto bootretry
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} iseq ${hook-attempt} 25 && goto end || sleep 10
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} goto hookretry
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} :bootretry
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} inc boot-attempt
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} echo Boot attempt ${boot-attempt} at ${unixtimestr}
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} sanboot ${tgt1}::::${iqn} ${tgt2}::::${iqn} ||
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} iseq ${boot-attempt} 25 && goto end || sleep 10
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} goto bootretry
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} :end
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} echo Boot failed
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/[removed-ProjectID]/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} poweroff
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Velostrata manager is waiting for disk to be online. Please check whether you have allocated a sufficient storage quota  in GCP for  Compute Engine. Please make sure whether you meet the network access requirements prior to migration. You can see more information on network access requirements in the link[1](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.2/concepts/planning-a-migration/network-access-requirements).

Also please look at the additional Windows adaptation script provided by Google Cloud Migrate for Compute Engine for Windows system[2](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.5/how-to/prepare-vms-servers/windows-adaptations). Some OS adaption Scripts are provided by default.

Comment: Hi Pralove, Thanks for answering it. We have sufficient storage quota and the firewalls are created properly. I will check the firewall rules again as per your suggestions. For Windows systems, Google Cloud Migrate for Compute Engine (formerly Velostrata) provides some OS adaptation scripts by default. If we want to use some user defined scripts then only we have to go for windows adaptions but it is different in the case of Linux. I will check further for troubleshooting it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Again I'm seeing the same errors almost. Please help.

Comment: ============================ port: 1 ============================
Failed to get serial port output. {}404 Not Found
{
\"code\" : 404,
\"errors\" : [ {
\"domain\" : \"global\",
\"message\" : \"The resource 'projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp03' was not found\",
\"reason\" : \"notFound\"
} ],
\"message\" : \"The resource 'projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp03' was not found\"
}

Comment: There are two different instances vmtestgcp02 and vmtestgcp03. Both the instances running the same OS? To fully debug, those error logs are not sufficient. The support bundle has more logs. https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.2/support/saving-a-support-bundle . There you can contact GCP support.

Comment: Yes. there are two instaces: Windows 2016 and Windows 2012. I have downloaded the support bundle. We dont have GCP support.

Comment: Your issue requires deep inspection of logs by the velostrata product team. You could either acquire a support package or file a new issue with issue tracker. https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#search_for_or_create_issues_and_feature_requests_by_product
GCP support may be able to help through that channel though it's generally reserved to file product issues and not to debug projects.